# My reputation went down by 50, no recently deleted questions nor answers

Tags: support, reputation

I just noticed that my rep went down by 50, I don't have any new reputation changes that would indicate that nor any deleted questions and answers, that could have caused this.

My guess would be it has something to do with documentation.

How can I track such reputation losses?

Comment: Go to http://stackoverflow.com/reputation and scroll to the bottom.

Comment: I can't see any evidence [from your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1509764/matas-vaitkevicius?tab=reputation)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ IIRC a part of reputation loss events are only visible to yourself, not to others.

Comment: @Stijn I had 15072.... ;( can't seem to find -50 anywhere but bounties

Comment: I'd suspect it may have to do with recalculations done for rep gained in documentation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I would think so too, probably one of my changes got reverted.....

Comment: Do you have the "show removed posts" box checked at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/users/1509764/matas-vaitkevicius?tab=reputation.  The reputation page hides these events by default.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Hi, I do...

Comment: Probably a recalc. Happened to me yesterday randomly too, lost some 200 rep in the process. CM's are still figuring out wtf exactly caused it.

Comment: Yeah, I see the entry "moderator recalcs rep: Scheduled: old rep = 15072, new rep = 15022 by Community" in your internal history, but no deletions, vote invalidations, or other events that triggered that. Guessing it's Documentation-related or a delayed recalculation from some other event.

Comment: @BradLarson Hi, Thanks Brad. Is there a way for user to see this?

Comment: At some point between Oct 5th (your last recalc) and today, your reputation got out of sync somewhere. After you deleted one of your questions today (which itself did not change your rep because there were no votes, but still schedules you for a recalc), your account got scheduled for a recalc and fixed it, but it's not entirely clear where the discrepancy came from.