# Invisible reputation loss

Tags: support, bug, reputation

I have reached 20000 reputation on november 21, however it seems almost all records of that fact have been erased. The only proof is my achievements tab which shows the privilege.

This screenshot was taken right now:

[image]

Up until today my reputation was over 20000. Yesterday it was around 20040. Today my reputation is at 19953.

The reputation tab shows as if nothing has happened. The show removed posts checkbox is checked. There are no notifications of any kind. What's more interesting is that the reputation page (stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows as if I have never reached 20000. It seems the entire history has been silently recalculated. And I have lost 100 reputation in the process.

I have no problem with losing reputation, but I would like an explanation why it happened.

Comment: @Braiam That answer says that any reputation change is visible in https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, however mine isn't. I have reached over 20000 but there is zero record of it anywhere. This isn't a duplicate of that post.

Comment: @2501 I understand completely.  But that page will not show loses of reputation from deletion and such.  When posts are deleted, the simply no longer appear on that page

Comment: @2501 at the bottom of http://stackoverflow.com/users/4082723/2501?tab=reputation there is a box that says "show removed posts".  Is that checked?

Comment: If you earned and lost rep on the same question on the same day it probably wouldn't show in the rep table. The fact that you went over 20k would have triggered the notification.

Comment: @psubsee2003 it will not show negative if in the same day IIRC.

Comment: @psubsee2003 That isn't exactly correct. All downvote loss is visible, all bounty loss is visible. User removal loss isn't.

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes it is checked.

Comment: @Paulie_D I was over 20000 for almost a week. This is explained in the answer.

Comment: @2501 my choice of wording in "negative reputation events" was misleading.  I specific meant stuff like "user was removed" and "deleted posts".  They will not show up in the /reputation page

Comment: This is really weird. Are you sure an answer or two wasn't deleted?

Comment: @AndrewLi My answers were not deleted.

Comment: @2501 do you have any reputation associated with `[documentation]'.  I know when the recalc was done after the changed the rep rules, there were some people who didn't see the change immediaitely and dind't catch up with them until a week or 2 later

Comment: @psubsee2003 Yes I have documentation rep, but not much. I think my total documentation rep is 200-400 rep.

Comment: @psubsee2003 that was more than (a month?) ago. They had 20000 up until today. IMO unlikely

Comment: @AndrewLi there's not a lot of other explanations.

Comment: possibly related, or at least relavant: [My reputation went down by 50, no recently deleted questions nor answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336236/my-reputation-went-down-by-50-no-recently-deleted-questions-nor-answers)

Comment: @psubsee2003 I remember approximately a month or so ago, there were documentation recalculations. At that time the change to my rep was insignificant.

Comment: @2501 my only other guess is animuson's comment at the end of the post you linked.  At some point in time your rep got out of synch and something recently triggered a recalculation, which corrected it

Comment: Hmm, heck of a coincidence.  You stopped posting answers when "20k" started being displayed.  That was actually 19,500.

Comment: John Cena did it.

Comment: What if several of your answers were removed by a mod? If they haven't been in the site for long, the rep is deducted when this happens.

Comment: Hmm, I experienced the same exact thing about (approximately) a week ago. (Though, I just thought it was a doc-rep recalc and brushed it off.)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard Yeah. A note in the reputation tab informing a user would be nice.

Comment: @2501 exact thing happened to me today(rep as well as score reduced), no clue about what just happened