# Reason for loss in reputation

Tags: support, reputation

I just lost 101 reputation points on SO.

Neither the reputation [tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2912665/cincout?tab=reputation) nor the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/reputation) helped me to understand the reason. I also checked the 'deleted recent posts' checkbox at the bottom of the reputation tab.

What am I missing?

In case it is of any help, I downvoted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479915/woocommerce-wordpress-out-of-hours/41219570#41219570), which later got removed, thus having no impact on my reputation. I had 3190 before this event, and now its 3089.

1. The closest reason I see is:

> one of your posts receives 6 spam or offensive flags: −100

If this is the case, how can I know which post was the culprit?

2. I also earned the secret "Don't Wanna Taco 'Bout it" hat round about the same time. Coincidence?

I was able to obtain a screenshot as SO was open on my personal machine:

[image]

Also, the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2016-01-01/2912665#2912665) confirm the same. (Thanks Eran for the link.)

And, there are [no deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2912665). (Yet again, thanks Eran.)

Comment: Was SO the first community that you joined? Because otherwhise it might be that you lost your association bonus (101 rep). This normally shouldn't happen I believe. Did you delete / request deletion/disassociation of one of your community accounts?

Comment: @Seth SO indeed was my first community. Hence I never received association bonus for the same!

Comment: @Seth - you can't lose the association bonus.

Comment: @ChrisF I see, thanks :)

Comment: I can't see any indication that you had any of your posts flagged as spam or rude/offensive. Are you 100% sure your reputation was 3,190 and not 3,090?

Comment: @ChrisF Yes I am. I was about to take the screenshot here on Meta, but refreshed the page in haste only to reset the number back to 3089

Comment: @CinCout Press "Back" a few times, you should end up seeing a cached version of the previously visited page, including your old rep count.

Comment: @Seth Not able to reproduce. Not sure if web archives would help.

Comment: When did this happen? A few hours ago?

Comment: @ayhan Yes. Somewhere around 2 hours ago

Comment: Do you have any recent deleted questions or answers?

Comment: The reputation leagues show your rep from last night was 3190 (http://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/year/stackoverflow/2016-01-01/2912665#2912665) , so you really lost rep. Perhaps someone deleted a question in which you had multiple upvotes. You can check your recently deleted answers.

Comment: Try this link - http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2912665.

Comment: I once had a case when user's entire account got deleted which resulted in loss of reputation for me, so it's possible that same happened here.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota that kind of change is noted in your profile.

Comment: Relevant: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338813/invisible-reputation-loss

Answer (score 55):

I've looked at your rep history to try and see what happened and there is nothing that sticks out as being odd.  I do see that your rep earlier today was 3189 and it's now about 100 less, it appears that your reputation was stuck from an earlier recalculation - possibly a Docs recalc.

I've checked the database and your rep is 3089.  I'm guessing that your downvote of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479915/woocommerce-wordpress-out-of-hours/41219570#41219570) which resulted in a -1, and then the subsequent deletion of the answer which restored the 1 rep - triggered a recalculation which corrected your current rep.

Side note: this had nothing to do with the award of the Taco Hat.

Comment: Should you really be calling out a specific downvote? Not sure this answer needs to specify the post involved.

Comment: @DavidG The user linked to it in the question and said they downvoted it, so I'm not disclosing anything secret.

Comment: The answer was deleted, so only visible for 10k+ users. No obvious name shaming involved.

Comment: That's fair I guess, but it still makes me a little uncomfortable.

Comment: Hat information leak!

Comment: Thanks for taking time your time to look into it. So is there a way to confirm your guess, or this is the maximum I can get?

Comment: @CinCout I think this is about as good as it's going to get. I'm not seeing anything in your history that stands out.