# Unexplained reputation changes

Tags: support

Every once in awhile, I'll notice a sudden unexplained change in my reputation. For example, I suddenly lost 20 reputation the other day without my Reputation tab showing anyone downvoting any of my posts. I assume that a question I had an upvoted answer for got deleted (or something like that); is there a way to find out exactly what happened?

Comment: @Makoto I did look at that and the answer there didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Also read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339836/reason-for-loss-in-reputation